# what will i loose during the root process?

Tags: backup

when i root my device what will i loose ?? will rooting wipe my device ?? i don't care about contacts nor applications data the most important this is my media !!! it means a lot for me no just media !! PDF files and everything else i added to the phone storage other then the application ??? please can somebody help because i want to root my phone to use titanium backup so i can have access to all my backup data anywhere ??

Answer (score 1):

Let's get it straight. I'm aware of two techniques that can root an Android device. Both has merits and demerits.

1. **Unlock Bootloader →install a custom Recovery → root device using custom Recovery**

   This method will definitely wipe **every thing** because it resets the phone back to a state you received from your OEM (OTA update is exception). So if your rooting method requires unlocking Bootloader then do consider taking a backup of your Internal SD card.

   **Merit**: Clean, easy, and you're aware of what's going on at any stage.
    
   **Demerit**: Because of security concerns data is lost for good.
2. **Using an app on Android or PC**

   There are Android apps like [Framaroot](http://framaroot.net/) (see **Methods/apps** [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/1185/96277)), or PC apps like [Kingoroot](http://www.kingoapp.com/android-root/devices.htm) which can root your device without caring for the state of the Bootloader. They rely on an un-patched vulnerability in your Android device. [Here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/22885/96277) is a good answer that explains the working of such apps.

   **Merit**: Device rooted without data loss (usually).
   **Demerit**: If the app isn't open source then you're at the mercy of the app since you don't know what's going on.

Now that an understanding is developed for what will be lost or saved in each method, we will now proceed for backup of Internal SD card.

### Consider this rule

**Always take backup**  before tinkering with `/system` (rooting affects it) or any other uncommon firmware partition.

### About Backup

Taking backup of Internal SD card is trivial. Plug your device into your PC and do a copy-paste of all the content (or your important content) from Internal SD card into PC. I prefer to take backup [by running a file server  and  USB tethering on Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/106323/96277) but you may use MTP or any [other technique](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/91901/96277) like `adb pull <SOURCE> <TARGET>`.

Comment: Losing your warranty depends upon your country's law and OEM's policy. Mostly, you will lose the warranty once the device is rooted but I've noted that EU has a law which protects your warranty even if you root your device.

Answer (score 0):

When you root your android device you will loose nothing except your warranty. On some devices there are still tricks to get your warranty back by resetting the flash counter etc.
You will loose nothing by the rooting process. However, there always is a slight chance that there goes something wrong and you may loose your data. I never had it myself, but I suggest you to make a backup of all your data. Most of the data should be synced automatically with Google servers, but you still need to back up your photos, documents etc.

When you are rooted there are better ways to backup your data with apps like titanium backup, ROM toolbox etc.

Hope my answer helps!

Answer (score -1):

Use this App - http://www.moborobo.com/products/ to make a decent backup of everything including your installed Apps. Then also copy both SD CARD and Internal Memory contents to a backup location then try your rooting. I rooted a phone and the worst happened. But i restored everything except my active chats in WhatsApp.

Good luck!

Comment: Are you affiliated to the product?

Answer (score -2):

You will lose nothing except your warranty.

Comment: Man guys if you downvote someone for answering then tell him why you downvotedthe post. You WONT lose anything by rooting but you will lose data by flashing wrong images, autoroots etc.

Comment: Maybe the guys who downvoted this answer owns a [OnePlus device](https://oneplus.net/support/answer/will-rooting-or-unlocking-the-bootloader-void-my-warranty).

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. if this would e answered correctly by the guy who ones that specific device i would understand the downvote. but I remember that there is some rule here prohibiting posts based personal opinion.