# What exactly is the procedure while granting root access on a device?

Tags: root-access

I have read a lots of articles regarding root. But I haven't found any specific information on what's the proccess and the steps that are required to grand root access on a device.
For example. If I copy "su" script and install Superuser.apk, I immediately grant root access?

And last but not least, I want to program a temporary root application.(Root until device reboots) Does that even possible?

Comment: To the first question: No, you need a service (daemonsu, invoked by init.d, which has root access already) to manage root access, but the procedure isn't any more complicated than copying 2 additional files. To the second question: Yes this is possible, if you remove everything related to your rooting procedure on shutdown of the device.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Do you know any good way on how to invoke daemonsu or a how to get all this proccess done? Like a tutorial?

Comment: Not a tutorial, but it needs to be invoked during `init`, so putting a script into `/system/etc/init.d` will likely be enough to launch it. The hard part is: Make sure the kernel supports `init.d` and how do you even write to `/system`.

Comment: I see..what do you mean by "putting a script in init.d". What should this script contain?

Comment: Everything that is needed to invoke `daemonsu`. For example SuperSU's way: `#!/system/bin/sh
/system/xbin/daemonsu --auto-daemon &`. This launches `daemonsu` in the background (`&`) with the parameter `--auto-daemon`.

Comment: And after invoking this service.. Then what? How   will I ccontinue?

Comment: Then you are better off asking the creators of SuperSU, Superuser, KingRoot etc. I only know about the basics of gaining root access on an Android device.

Comment: Yeah and thanks for replying! In case you have a Facebook account, can I add you, so we can chat more easily?

Comment: @GiantTree I believe Captain Lemon simply wants to know how to makes lemonade. Not learn how to grow lemon and make sugar :) If you add the phone information on your question, I can teach you how to root it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does rooting work?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22884/how-does-rooting-work)

Answer (score 0):

Every phone model and manufacturer will have different processes for gaining root access. Make absolutely sure that you are following the specific instructions for the device, kernel and software version for the phone. Otherwise, you can easily "brick" your phone, effectively turning it into a paperweight.

That being said, here is a great [resource for rooting Android devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/1185/145638).