# The process of rooting

Tags: rooting, superuser, bloatware

Rooting is the process of installing the "Super User" account in Android.
Which are the processes carried out in rooting ?

I mean how actually it's done ?

Apps like Kingroot can root many devices in one click. But how to root Android phones through computer ?

I am asking this question because my phone (LYF Flame 7)  which is unsupported by many 3rd party rooting apps so I have to find myself a way to root it. I have found many device-specific articles but found none general methods. 
Kernel is 
Android 3.10.65 svn 621
cme@cme-server #01

I really need to root to get rid of these annoying bloatwares .. More and more bloatwares are getting installed in every unstoppable OTA updates.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Have you already consulted our [rooting tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info) and followed the links to further details from there? Especially [How do I root my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575) and [How does rooting work?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/22884/16575)

Comment: Thank you for your answer Izzy. Yeah , I haven't checked that section yet.  And I am going to check it now.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't give you a step by step tutorial on how to root your phone, here are the basics for a manual method.

Firstly, you have to unlock the bootloader. This will void your warranty but will allow you to continue to the next step. Remember that I won't be responsible for any damages made to your phone.

Next, you will need to flash a custom recovery which will give you access to all the files on your device and let you wipe the system, install custom ROMs and more.

The last step is to flash SuperSu to the device using the recovery tool. Your device will be rooted.

Comment: To unlock the bootloader , the following things should be done. You please check  if I am  missing something .

1.  Enable developer options.
2.  Enable OEM Unlocking.
3.  Enable USB debugging.
4.  Connect the phone to the computer.

5. Boot the device into fastboot mode. 
6.Execute OEM Unlocking command.

And done.

Is it right ??
Can this procedure be applied to any phone regardless of manufacturer ?

Comment: @AthulBC Unlocking bootloader is definitely OEM-specific, like Samsung who provides a unlocker app for all Galaxy phones (possibly not including Note 7 which can cause disasters). There isn't a manufacturer independent method to unlock BL. However most phones do not have BL locked out-of-the-box.

Comment: How to check if my bootloader is already unlocked or not ? Even if it is locked , can I unlock it with just the fastboot OEM Unlocking command ?