# Is it possible to use rooting method of a device on a device having same model number yet different baseband number

Tags: root-access

I have recently bought Samsung Galaxy J Docomo. Upon spending countless hours on the internet searching for roots, I could only find the root for build id: LRX21V.SC02FOMUGOI4. Does there exist a root for Build ID: LRX21V.SC02FOMSGPL2 (which is on my phone)? If yes, can somebody point me in the correct direction?

Let me know if you want further details. Thanks in advance.

Moreover, is it possible for me to use the available  rooting technique on my mobile (despite the different firmware versions)?

Here's some more information regarding the firmwares.

Phone Samsung GALAXY J
Model SC-02F
PDA Version SC02FOMSGPL2
CSC Version SC02FDCMGPL2
PHONE Version SC02FOMSGPL2
Region DCM
Country Japan 
Build Date 09.12.2016
Changelist 5774932
OS Lollipop
OS Version 5.0

Phone Samsung GALAXY J
Model SC-02F
PDA Version SC02FOMUGOI4
CSC Version SC02FDCMGOI4
PHONE Version SC02FOMUGOI4
Region DCM
Country Japan 
Build Date 09.09.2015
Changelist 5774932
OS Lollipop
OS Version 5.0

Answer (score 0):

- Rooting methods are often device, device variant and OS specific (though some work across device-boundaries). In your question both devices are the same except PDA which is same but with minor variations – I couldn't find the exact difference on internet
- Baseband has **nothing to do with rooting** process . See [What does "to root a phone" mean?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/236/131553) and [How does rooting work?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/22884/131553). So you are perfectly fine adopting the same rooting process
- If you plan to stay with stock OS, there is nothing to be concerned about. If you decide to flash a custom ROM, use ROM specifically meant for your device variant -custom ROMs usually do not touch bootloader , modem and other low level stuff and write to `/system`