# Android 10 forensics - Root a cellphone without SD Card and without installing any external apps

Tags: rooting, android-10, magisk

I would like to root my Samsung J6 mobile phone that is running Android 10 in order to apply forensically sounding techniques on it (basically recovering deleted data etc). So far, as I researched on web, all of the rooting methods require installing of softwares such as magisk to a component such as either SD card or internal memory of mobile phone. The thing is, I don't have an SD Card inserted on the phone, and I don't want to install any external software into my cellphone memory. Is there any way to root this cell phone without installing any app into its memory(rooting via using only connected computer)? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: All you need is the *nix su binary. Magisk and SuperSu are just tools for controlling access to the su binary to prevent its misuse. Every time a process tries to execute su, these tools will prompt you for granting the permission or let you know in some other way.

Comment: @ashu Unfortunately it is not that simple. The su binary is just the tip of the iceberg. On modern devices also SELinux has to be considered.

Comment: In the process of rooting a device (unless you use an exploit to temporary gain root permissions) erasing all user data is a mandatory step. On an encrypted device (all modern devices should be encrypted by default) this means that afterwards any data recovery is impossible because the encryption key had changed. On some older Samsung devices there is a vulnerability in the MTP protocol which would allow to root the device via USB, but in Android 10 this should be already fixed.

Comment: @Robert makes sense!!

Comment: @ashu `su` binary alone hasn't been working since Android 4.3. You need to run a background daemon: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217949/218526

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover data when everything is locked (FRP, OEM)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/227110)